# Adding UI elements to scrolviewer dynamically, win phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I know how to add children to panels. It is like this
stackpanel.children.add(uielement);

But I have a scrollviewer inside stackpanel.
I wanted to add textblocks and other elements inside the scrollviewer but there is no function to add children to scrollviewer. 
I tried to add another stackpanel inside the scrollview and add elements to it... but if I add elements dynamically to the stackpanel defined inside scrollviewer the elements show right but there is no scroll. If I do the same that is:

```
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel x:Name="StckPanel">
              <TextBlock Text="etc" />
         </StackPanel>
     </ScrollViewer>
```

Doing this enabled the scroll. But If I add elements to the stack panel using
StckPanel.Children.Add(Textblock Object);
It does add the elements but the scroll is now disabled. 
Here is what I did:
The XAML code is

```
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel x:Name="Hello"></StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

In my c# file I did this:

```
        TextBlock x= new TextBlock();
        x.Text="Here it goes";
        StckPanel.Children.Add(x);
```

But when I do this the scroll is disabled. I am not able to scroll.

So I need to know why is the scroll not working here. And how am I supposed to add child elements inside ScrollViewer.
As in XAML we can add UIElements inside the tags of ScrollViewer. Why cant we do the same using c#.

Comment: Show the code of how you are adding the ScrollViewer and StackPanel.

Comment: I am using the same code as above and adding elements to stackpanel names SckPanel. But that does not enable the scroll. If I add to the stackPanel named StckPanel by hard coding the xml, the scroll is enabled. But if I dynamically add the elements from c# than the scroll does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the problem. I was not specifying the height width and margins properly. As a result this messed up the scroll somehow.